# Get next Tuesday and Thursday from current date in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, date

I need to display the dates of the next Tuesday and the next Thursday from the current date. If the current date is Wednesday then I would need the next Thursday and then the next Tuesday the following week.

I've gone around in circles with solutions like the below but I haven't been able to manipulate these to give me the results I need. Any ideas?

```
var monday: Date {
return Calendar(identifier: .iso8601).date(from: Calendar(identifier: .iso8601).dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: Date()))!
}
// Monday, November 6, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM
```

and

```
let f = DateFormatter()
f.weekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date())]
// Saturday
```

Comment: Have a look at the Calendar method `nextDate(after:matching:matchingPolicy:repeatedTimePolicy:direction:)`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42185197.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Get the current weekday. If it's Tuesday or Wednesday set the order of the next both occurrences to `Thu, Tue` (5, 3) otherwise (3, 5):

```
var currentDate = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let currentWeekday = calendar.component(.weekday, from: currentDate)
let nextWeekdays = 3...4 ~= currentWeekday ? [5, 3] : [3, 5]
```

Then map the weekdays to the next occurrences with `nextDate(after: matching: matchingPolicy)`

```
let result = nextWeekdays.map { weekday -> Date in
    let components = DateComponents(weekday: weekday)
    let nextOccurrence = calendar.nextDate(after: currentDate, matching: components, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!
    currentDate = nextOccurrence
    return nextOccurrence
}
print(result)
```

Comment: Hey, this is great, thanks for the answer. No idea why someone down voted! Do you know how to determine which date is a Tues and which is a Thurs, struggling with that at the moment

Comment: The result are `Date` instances which contain the weekday information otherwise get it from the `nextWeekdays` array (3 = Tue, 5 = Thu)

Comment: Ah of course, I knew there was something simple I was missing, thanks!